# JBOSS JMX Remoting client memory leak

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jmx

We notice the memory leak while working with JBOSS jmx remoting library in web application

We initialize the JMX connection factory as below

```
try {
            this.jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, auth);
            if (this.jmxConnector != null) {
                MBeanServerConnection mbs = this.jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
                if (mbs != null) {
                    this.mbs = mbs;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connected = false;
        }
```

Then use mbean server connection after scheduled interval say 60 secs to read the mbeans from above mbean server connection.

```
private Map<String, Object> getAttributesForMBean(ObjectName objectName, List<String> attributeNames) {

         HashMap<String, Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (String attributeName : attributeNames) {
            Object attributeValue = null;
            if (this.hasAttribute(objectName, attributeName)) {
                try {
                    attributeValue = this.mbs.getAttribute(objectName, attributeName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.warn("In getAttributes(), for " + objectName + ": " , e);
                }
            }
            attributeMap.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
        }
        return attributeMap;
    }
```

We see that RemoteConnectionChannel keeps accumulating XnioWorkerTaskPool and leads to memory leak.

Please let me know if anyone face this issue before with org/jboss/remotingjmx/remoting-jmx/ library

[Memory Leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg7N6.jpg)

Comment: Which version are you using? There were some memory leaks in XNIO and JMX in 7.1.1.Final. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-6254 https://issues.jboss.org/browse/REMJMX-45